# How to customize ASCII to EBCDIC table in Notepad++'s TextFX plugin?

Tags: notepad++, ebcdic

In Notepad++'s TextFX there is an embedded ASCII to EBCDIC table, but there is a reference to an custom table.

What is the path for the table?

Answer (score 2):

The file is loaded from `$(plugins)\Config\tidy\AsciiToEBCDIC.bin`. Use a hex editor to customize the mappings.